# find and reverse text in multiple files with tac command in linux

Tags: linux, reverse, file-manipulation

I am trying to reverse the order of multiple text files (for plotting purposes) which are essentially rows of numbers. I tried to do it with `tac` and combined it with `find` and `-exec` as

```
find ./dir1/dir2/ -name foo.txt -type f -exec tac {} \;
```

but this only gives the output on the screen and does not modify the files intended.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there - `tac` writes to `stdout` so you can simply redirect the output somewhere handy:

```
find .... \; > newfoo.txt
```

If you want each file reversed and written to the same location, something like this will do:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'tac "$1" > "$1"-new' -- {} \;
```

Cheers,

Comment: Actually it works but not the way I want it. This creates newfoo.txt in the current location of the terminal but not all the instances/locations where the files are found.

Comment: It seems to work but using sed or vim is much faster. The solution will help who are non-users of vim and sed!